# Is the Strong Limit of a Linear Operator in a Hilbert Space the Same as the Norm Limit?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

If $H$ is a Hilbert Space, and I have an operator $F:H  \rightarrow  H$ which is the limit of a sequence of operators $F_n$ with respect to the operator norm; and this same sequence of operators converges strongly to the zero function, is $F$ necessarily the zero function?

We have $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ||F - F_n|| = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sup_{||x|| = 1} ||(F - F_n)x|| = 0$ because of the norm convergence, and $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} F_n x = 0$ for each $x \in H$ because of the strong convergence.

I don't see how to make the fact that we are dealing with a Hilbert space matter.

Answer (score 2):

It would work in any normed space, since for any $x$, the sequence $(F_n(x),n\geqslant 1)$ converges to both $F(x)$ and $0$.

Comment: Okay, norm convergence implies pointwise convergence, and the limit is unique. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.